# Do nodes with vote=0 count when trying to determine if a quorum is available?

Tags: mongodb

I have a three member replica set.  We want to add a fourth hidden node to be used for reporting.  The configuration of this node would be priority=0, votes=0, hidden=true.

With three voting members, I can bring down any single node and still have a quorum for electing a primary.  After adding this new non-voting node (which will reside in a remote datacenter with spotty connectivity) I want to make sure that a failure of one of the three voting nodes will not take my replica set offline if the hidden node is offline or can't otherwise be reached by the replica set.

Does the replica set count non-voting nodes when trying to determine if there are enough reachable members to constitute a quorum, or are they ignored for purposes of elections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The election process will ignore non-voting nodes when deciding if they have a quorum or when electing a new primary.  Additionally, because the priority is 0, your non-voting node would never be considered an eligible candidate for becoming primary anyway.

Also note that by setting priority = 0, the node will never trigger an election check, so if it goes down the rest of the replica set really doesn't care.

However, interestingly enough, your non-voting, non-eligible-for-primary node can still veto an election if it recognizes an invalid election process.